# C++ program with gtk+

Tags: c++, gtk

I want to call gtk+ routines from a C++ program `test.cpp`, and he encountered a problem while building my program.

I am getting the following error:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.x 
test.cpp:1:22: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
# include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

Somehow I need to link to gtk+. What will be the correct compiler declarations get my program working.

Comment: Do you have the development headers for gtk installed on your system?

Comment: What do I have to install exactly? I am on GNU. I think GTK+ is provided by the distribution. How can I find out?

Comment: `find / -name gtk.h`?

Comment: I have installed `libgtkmm-3.0-dev`.

Comment: `find` is going to take forever

Comment: I have found it here:  `/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h`

Comment: You could use the `-I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/` flag when compiling your code to add it manually, [see here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html), for just that one compilation, but I would just add it to the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile a program using gtkmm, you need to use the following command:

```
g++ program.cc -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`
```

The `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0` part provides the include paths and the linker options.

Source: [The Flaming Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/), which you should Read.

Comment: Correct command and I get the application do as expected. I do not know about the manual, but I will read through.

Comment: @Zeus Because the people who wrote the documentation didn't make a pdf version of it? If you want a local copy you can install the libgtkmm-3.0-doc package, and read it using devhelp.

Comment: What a lazy bunch. I hate the endless clicking!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about *gtk* in particular but this is a simple file not found issue.

You need to be sure that your *system includes search path* contains a folder `gtk` in it which in turn has a file called `gtk.h`.

Please read about the [GCC search paths](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).

This is also likely a duplicated question so it will probably be closed off soon by the community.